# Generate a dictionnary in a list

Tags: python-2.7

So here's my problem, I have a list of characters generated randomly by a program.
I would like for each of those characters to have feelings towards each others.

Here is my code so far:

```
import random

# create characters

class CHARACTER:
    def __init__(self, name, surname, age, sexe, pragmatism,
        courage, intelligence, shyness, happiness, fear, hunger,
        comfort, feeling):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.age = age
        self.sexe = sexe
        self.pragmatism = pragmatism
        self.courage = courage
        self.intelligence = intelligence
        self.shyness = shyness
        self.happiness = happiness
        self.fear = fear
        self.hunger = hunger
        self.comfort = comfort
        self.feeling = feeling


characters = [] # list that will contain all the characters
feelingslist = []
sexe = ["Male", "Female"]

mname = ["John", "Mike", "Albert", "Henry", "Patrick", "Francis",
"Robert", "Simon", "Charles", "Charlie", "Connor", "Adam", "Blake", 
"Steven", "Edward", "Andrew", "Joe", "Gregory", "Brian", "Anthony", 
"Frank", "Billy", "Boris", "Edgar", "Elliott", "Erik", "Liam", "Kyron", 
"Ned", "Neil", "Ricky", "Ross", "Rich", "Roy", "Preston", "William", 
"Vladimir", "Zach", "Wyatt", "Tylor", "Thomas", "Spike"]

fname = ["Alessia", "Ally", "Bridgette", "Callie", "Jessica", 
"Debora", "Diana", "Elizabeth", "Clair", "Fran", "Hannah", 
"Helene", "Marie", "Laura", "Leslie", "Leyla", "Kiley", 
"Margaret", "Lola", "Maryjane", "Megan", "Rose", "Sofia", 
"Samantha", "Teresa", "Yolanda", "Teri", "Vicky", "Tricia", 
"Rose", "Rita", "Nita", "Paola", "Penelope", "Polly", 
"Nathalie", "Melody", "Morgane"]

lname = ["Smith", "Johnson", "Williams", "Jones", "Brown", "Miller", 
"Moore", "Taylor", "Thomas", "White", "Harris", "Thompson", "Garcia", 
"Allen", "Lewis", "Hall", "Young", "Clark", "Hill", "Lopez", "Carter", 
"Turner", "Collins", "Evans", "Campbell", "Nelson", "Parker", "Green", 
"Black", "Green", "Lee", "Martin"]


# the code below create 10 male and 10 female characters
# and puts them in the characters list.


for i in range(20):
    character = CHARACTER(random.choice(mname),
    random.choice(lname), random.randint(1,10), 
    random.choice(sexe), random.randint(1,10), random.randint(1,10),
    random.randint(1,10), random.randint(1,10),
    random.randint(1,10), random.randint(1,10),
    random.randint(1,10), random.randint(1,10), {})

    characters.append(character)
    i += 1

# assigning sexe to characters

for character in characters:
    if character.sexe == "Female":
        character.name = random.choice(fname)

# feelings

for character in characters:
    for character in characters:
        character.feeling[id(character)] = 5

# for each character in characters:
# add one feeling for each character

# printing characters

for character in characters:
    print character.name
    print character.surname
    print character.sexe
    print id(character)
    print character.feeling
    print " "
```

Now my problem with this is that the program only adds one entry for each characters like this:

Morgane
Garcia
Female
44880880
{44880880: 5}

So each character has an entry in their "feeling dictionnary" for themselves but not for the other ones.
I would like for each dictionnary to have one entry for every single other character in the program (so every character has an opinion about all the other ones)

Answer (score 1):

In your loop for setting feelings, you are using the same variable (`character`) to control both loops; they need to be different variables.

For example:

```
for char1 in characters:
    for char2 in characters:
        char1.feeling[id(char2)] = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright I finally solved this, just in case someone with the same problem reads that topic here is my solution:

```
characters_len = len(characters)

for character in characters:
    for i in range(characters_len):
        character.feeling[id(characters[i])] = 5
```

Thank you for your answers and putting me on the right path

Answer (score -1):

So I should do something like this:

```
characters_len = len(characters)

for character in characters:
    for i in range(characters_len):
        character.feeling[id(character)] = 5
        i+=1
```

?

Comment: No: you are still using `character` to identify both who's feeling is being set and who that feeling is about.  And don't change `i` explicitly; `for` is already taking care of that.

Comment: Ok, I see what the problem is but I'm not sure how to fixe it...how would you code it so that the program understands that it has to loop through all the characters for each character?